# How to call OpenGL functions in cross-platform apps?

Tags: macos, opengl

For example: on Linux function name `glBindVertexArray`, but on OS X function name `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glBindVertexArray` is already cross-plateform, and works on OS X.

You can find Apple documentation on this precise function [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glBindVertexArray.3G.html).